# Pyspark columns incorrectly converted to string after unnesting

Tags: python, pyspark

We have a Pyspark dataset where each column has a nested structure with parameters: string_value and int_value. For each column, only one value is filled (the other is null) and for the same parameter it's always the same value. However we don't know which column has string value and which integer value (the example is a simplification).

We try to extract the value of the column as the correct type (see code below) but it keeps returning as a string column.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType, LongType, StringType, StructType, StructField
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

schema = StructType([
   StructField("id", StringType(), True),
   StructField("string_col", StructType([
       StructField("string_value", StringType(), True),
       StructField("int_value", LongType(), True)
   ]), True),
   StructField("integer_col", StructType([
       StructField("string_value", StringType(), True),
       StructField("int_value", LongType(), True)
   ]), True)
   ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        Row(id='01', string_col=Row(string_value='A', int_value=None), integer_col=Row(string_value=None, int_value=65)),
        Row(id='02', string_col=Row(string_value='B', int_value=None), integer_col=Row(string_value=None, int_value=101)),
        Row(id='03', string_col=Row(string_value='C', int_value=None), integer_col=Row(string_value=None, int_value=384))
    ],
    schema)

df.printSchema()
```

returned schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- string_col: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- string_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- int_value: long (nullable = true)
 |-- integer_col: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- string_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- int_value: long (nullable = true)
```

attempt to extract columns:

```py
for expanded_col in ['string_col', 'integer_col']:
    df = (df.withColumn(expanded_col, 
                       F.when(F.col(expanded_col + '.int_value').isNotNull(), F.col(expanded_col + '.int_value').cast(IntegerType()))
                        .otherwise(F.col(expanded_col + '.string_value'))))
df.printSchema()
```

returned schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- string_col: string (nullable = true)
 |-- integer_col: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us fix and simplify your code

```
cmap = {'string_col': 'string_value', 'integer_col': 'int_value'}
for k, v in cmap.items():
    df = df.withColumn(k, F.col(k)[v])
```

For pyspark versions `>=3.3.0`, you can use the one liner

```
df = df.withColumns({k: F.col(k)[v] for k, v in cmap.items()})
```

---

```
df.show()
+---+----------+-----------+
| id|string_col|integer_col|
+---+----------+-----------+
| 01|         A|         65|
| 02|         B|        101|
| 03|         C|        384|
+---+----------+-----------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- string_col: string (nullable = true)
 |-- integer_col: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is that I do not have the definition that you wrote in cmap. The columns in the setup are called string_col and integer_col just for simplicity. In reality I have many columns and I need to determine from the data which are numeric by checking which contain value in the int_value parameter.

Comment: You can construct the cmap from the first (or any other) row and the schema: `cmap=dict([(c.name,'int_value' if df.head()[c.name]['int_value'] is not None else 'string_value') for c in df.schema if c.name != 'id'])`